# How do you play a (MIDI) sound in a Windows 10 UWP App?

Tags: c#, windows, uwp

I just started to work with Visual Studio Community 2015 and was trying to create a simple virtual piano app that plays the respective key when clicked.
I already have the layout for the keys but I can't find anything on how to make an actual sound. I'm working with Visual C# and apparently the System.Media namespace doesn't work with apps so I ran out of possibilities.

Is there an alternative with UWP apps?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.midi.aspx

Comment: also look at https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/AudioCreation

Comment: Check https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/09/21/midi-enhancements-in-windows-10/

Answer (score 0):

You can use Windows.Device.Midi to play. Here's the link : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/midi